# JQuery switch class based on value

Tags: jquery

I Need a little JQuery Help.

HTML

```
<body
<div id="mnRow" class="mnRow">
    <columns.Column field="Title" />
    <columns.Column field="AlertLevel" />
    <columns.Column field="Body" />      
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .low-risk{
     background-color: green;}

   .medium-risk{
    background-color: orange;}

  .high-risk{
   background-color: red;}
```

I'd like to add the class' from the CSS when Column field equals low, medium and high.

Any help is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: how they change? where they come from? you need to give some more information. if you create them you can check at the time and write directly or  use $(...).addClass

Comment: Do you know what this syntax comes from? :`<columns.Column field="....` Because I certainly don't. If you have an issue using jQuery, then post that as well. Better yet understand how to create a [mcve], because what you have posted makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom attribute selector of Jquery and add class dynamically.

```
$("columns.Column[field='low']").addClass("low-risk")
```

Ideally you should create a mapping object key as field name (like "low") and value as class name (like "low-risk") and loop through that object to perform addClass.